# reading a file line by line and store the two strings each time into two different variables

Tags: bash

I have a file with each line containing two absolute path file names separated by a space.
I just want to have each of them into a different variable in order to copy the second one onto the first one.
I tried it with sed + regex and variable substitution, no reaction.

```
sed -e 's/(.*)\s(.*)/$2 $1/g'  filename
```

in order to use then /bin/cp $line then for each read line...

Next I searched here for while loops in bash but none seems to work properly and simply.
In perl it would be so easy but I can't use it in this case.
I have to do it out from a bash script...

Any good idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
while IFS= read -r file1 file2; do 
    cp $file2 $file1
done < file
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't even now you could do that. Nice one!

Comment: many thanks @Jaypal, but it does not work neither:                   
libs=`cat libs.txt`
echo "$libs"
echo LOOP:
while IFS= read -r file1 file2; do
   cp i$file2 $file1
   echo file2=$file2 file1=$file1
done < "$libs"                                                    .
.
.
./swap_strings.sh 
file1 file2
file3 file4
LOOP:
./swap_strings.sh: line 9: file1 file2
: No such file or directory

cat file1
file1
cat file3
file3

Comment: sorry for the format! I don't understand how to do it right....sorry for the name confusion:-):.....many thanks @fedorqui, but it does not work neither:                   
libs=`cat libs.txt`
echo "$libs"
echo LOOP:
while IFS= read -r file1 file2; do
   cp i$file2 $file1
   echo file2=$file2 file1=$file1
done < "$libs"                                                    .
.
.
./swap_strings.sh 
file1 file2
file3 file4
LOOP:
./swap_strings.sh: line 9: file1 file2
: No such file or directory

cat file1
file1
cat file3
file3...........................

Comment: Replace `libs = cat libs.txt` with just `libs = libs.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following loop:

```
while read line; do
  first = ${line%% ?*}
  second = ${line##?* }
  cp $first $second
done < filename
```

Where filename is the file you wish to split.

Comment: Thanks @noctua, unfortunately also unsuccessfull, ..... it says:.....line 11: file1 file2: No such file or directory......line11 is: done < "$filename"...... very strage this! ---- jannis ---

Comment: Replace `libs = cat libs.txt` with `libs = libs.txt`.

Comment: SOLVED: The problem was that the file read contained a \r\n at the end of each line which I got rid of by using: myline=`echo -n $line | tr -d "\r"` after reading each line. I just tried it with your proposal but I'm sure it'll work with any other too.  Many thanks to all for your help...

Answer (score 0):

In sed, you have to backslash the parentheses to give them the special meaning. Also, the captured groups are referenced by `\1`, not `$1`:

```
sed -e 's/\(.*\)\s\(.*\)/\2 \1/g'  filename
```

I am not sure the `/g` is needed, but you provided no sample data, so we cannot tell. It would probably not do what you wanted for lines with more than two paths as the `*` is greedy:

```
a b c d e -> e a b c d
```

Comment: you are right the /g isn't necessary because I have only one space in each line and thus only one occurrence....................Nevertheless the input remains unchanged................the file consists of 2 lines: 1: file1 file2 and 2: file3 file4    --- jannis

Comment: @user2355173: As given, the command does not change the file. It prints the new contents to standard output. To change the file, you have to specify `-i~` if supported by your `sed`, or redirect the output to a new file via `> newfile`.

Comment: This works:  sed -e 's/\(.*\)\s\(file2\)/\2 \1/' libs.txt ....... this also works:.....sed -e 's/\(.*\)\s\(file.\)/\2 \1/' libs.txt........  this also: .......  this not: ..... sed -e 's/\(.*\)\s\(f.+\)/\2 \1/' libs.txt

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `awk`, it's simple:

```
awk '{print $2 " " $1}' sample > sample2
```

Comment: You don't need empty quotes in the middle. Use of `,` should suffice.

Comment: @asclepix, many thanks too, but this way I get printed only the first string of a 2 lines file with each 2 strings... quite strange! :-(